# Setup YubiKey login on OpenBSD

Tags: authentication, openbsd, yubikey

How can I configure YubiKey-based login on OpenBSD without relying on the YubiKey Personalization GUI?

I attempted to set up YubiKey login on OpenBSD by following various online tutorials that explain how to use the yubkey-personalization-gui. However, this method did not work for me. I am now searching for a way to achieve this without using a GUI application. Can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: You want to set up a user, or SSH login? OpenBSD supports YubiKey out of the box.